# Grails : Spring Security Core - how to sort by account/user with default configuration

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am currently working through an issue of sorting using Spring Security Core. I am list users by role and with the recommended setup will require a lot more code. What would be the best route to sort on Account/User attributes using Spring Security Core/Shiro?

This is how I am currently populating a list and count.

```
def accountRoles = AccountRole.findAllByRole(role, [max: max, offset: offset])
def accountInstanceTotal = AccountRole.countByRole(role)
def accountInstanceList = accountRoles.collect(){ it.account }
```

**Account**

```
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    AccountRole.findAllByAccount(this)*.role
}
```

Default configuration doesn't have a hasMany relationship to lookup by role on Account/User.

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.